# Getting NoSuchFileException after migrating to java11

Tags: spring-boot, maven-3, java-11, maven-surefire-plugin

I have unit test method that uses resources related to test folder in child, it works fine when i am running this project but when i run the parent it appends the parent path to my relative string value `JsonFile` not the current project path

```
    JsonFile = "src/test/resources" + "fileName";
    System.out.println(Paths.get("").toAbsolutePath());
    String input = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(JsonFile)));
```

I am using openJDK11 , SureFire plugin 3.0.0-M3 and springboot 2.1.5.RELEASE. 
why this different behavior of
    `mvn clean install -Pjava11`
java11 is profile exists in parent pom

I tried to override profile java11 and change the version of SureFire Plugin  but it isn't useful, i don't know exactly where is the problem ? it works fine with java 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually after a lot of search i found that Path.get is related to file system not the working directory [link shows that](https://exchange-eme6.itn.ftgroup/owa/redir.aspx?C=zkWnvb16xopOZ-1HAqU393PbeI2Vyluhg7nH0vy98SCFh1i2IjHXCA..&URL=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F49222296%2Fnot-able-to-load-file-from-maven-resources-with-paths-get) 
 after that i changed the mechanism for getting resource files that exists in test folder using classLoader like

`ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
 File file = new File(classLoader.getResource(fileName).getFile());
 JsonFile = file.getAbsolutePath();`

it works fine with parent and child `mvn clean install -Pjava11`
it isn't obvious what i added to change the mechanism of Path.get() 
but it wasn't changed from jdk 7